# Phasing partially phased genomic data

Tags: genomics, genotyping, exome, phasing

I am trying to create an integrated callset with coding regions from phased exomes and noncoding regions from a genotyping array.  I would like to merge the data together in the correct phase.  Since the exomes are already phased with read informed phasing, I don't want to rephase them because some of the phasing changes after doing this.  Is there a way to statistically phase genetic data that has already been partially phased?

My data is in VCF format.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from @user438383, converted from comment:*

I would recommend checking out [shapeit4](https://odelaneau.github.io/shapeit4/) as it is able to integrate statistical phasing and read-based phasing like you are after. The manual page for WhatsHap might also be useful for you:

https://whatshap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html